# Print an image using don's Bluetooth Serial Plugin

Tags: angular, ionic2, asp.net-web-api2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I have a Epson TM-P20 thermal printer. I used [this link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/bluetooth-serial/) to print text from the ionic 3 app to the printer. My issue is, i don't know how to print an image using this plugin.

I use WebAPI2 as my web service, I loaded the image and converted the image to base64,

```
public string getLogo()
    {
        var file = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/logocogbw.png");
        return Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(file));
}
```

How can i print image using this plugin? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**

This is what [**Owner of the plugin**](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial/issues/136#issuecomment-109678333) says:

> You probably need to convert the image to a format the printer can
>   understand. Maybe something like PCL or PostScript?
>
> This plugin can send binary data. The write method accepts text or
>   binary data. See the quick examples in the docs
>   https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial#write

Another [**useful link**](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial/issues/207)

**Old Answer:**

You need to do it like this:

```
let data=this.getLogo();//get image data
this.bluetoothSerial.write(data).then(success, failure);// write into port using Bluetooth
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it, the printer prints the base64 data as text.

Comment: You cannot do it directly please see the updated post.

Comment: Is it possible to print via ESC/POS commands? I found that `GS ( L   /   GS 8 L` this command has to do something with printing the image

Comment: See this: https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial/issues/207#issuecomment-212255993

Comment: I'll try to write my own plugin. I don't know whether i can make it work.  :(

Comment: Yep, That thing too a great option. Good Luck!